# Can Android have multiple listeners?

Tags: android

Say I have 5 buttons. For each button I want to be able to fire a listener.
Once the listener is fired I want fire an async task in my sdk, and then have the sdk return the status of the async task.

1) Do I write a separate listener/ button? I read somewhere I can have only one registered listener in android, if thats true how do I handle many listeners?

2) How do I return postExecute call result from SDK to the api level?

Comment: "From SDK to the API level".  What do you mean?  "Have the SDK return the status"?

Comment: The async task is called in the sdk which is not shown to the user its internal. The user needs to see just the result from postExecute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Do I write a separate listener/ button? I read somewhere I can have only one registered listener in android, if thats true how do I handle many listeners?

A View can only have one listener of each type, ie a Button cannot have two `OnClickListeners`. Don't confuse this with the fact that one listener can be attached to multiple Views, ie ButtonA and ButtonB can have the same `OnClickListener`

> 2) How do I return postExecute call result from SDK to the api level?

Your terminology isn't right, but you'll figure it out as you go. Typically `onPostExecute()` will call another method or work directly with a View:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    doSomething(result);
    textView.setText(result);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the postexecute stuff.       so I culd have button1.setOnMyListener(new OnMyListener),  button2.setOnMyListner2(new OnMyListener2) - but is this the best way to do it? second question if this is correct, then in the sdk how would I know which listener is called?

Comment: Sam, in a situation where there are no buttons can I have multiple listeners or does android allow just one registered listener?

Comment: "in a situation where there are no buttons" The Buttons are just an example these rules apply to any View. "how would I know which listener is called?" If you set the same listener to multiple Views use `view.getId()` to check which View was actually clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is if you setup one listener in your activity, and then handle multiple buttons. You can do this with the [OnKeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html) class. You then do a switch on which key was hit, setup cases for the buttons you wish to act on, and start your `AsyncTask`.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "return postExecute". But if you look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) you can see how to use the proper parameters to return a result into onPostExecute. When you instantiate your subclass of `AsyncTask` you can easily pass in the activity or context you wish to perform a call back on.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple listeners and depending on what you want to do with them, you can have one for each button. As far as the `postExecute()`, it runs on the UI thread so you can show your result from there or do whatever you want with it. For more details, you will need to provide some of the code you have tried and explain exactly where you are having trouble. If you haven't already, go through the

**[Android Docs about getting started](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html)**

**[This link describes AsynTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)**

Comment: in the api the user can set separate listener for each button, but at the sdk level how do i figure out what listener was called by the user?

Comment: I think you are confused on the terminology but you will get it. The application knows what listener is attached to which button when you set that listener and it knows which button was clicked.